# context.savechanges() giving error while insert

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, savechanges

why i am getting null error for JobSeekerId, i have passing all the mandatory values through parameter but context.savechanges() returning me the error

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'JobseekerId', table
>   'Sample1.dbo.JobseekerBackgroundDetail'; column does not allow nulls.
>   INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.

but i am sure i am passing the jobseekerid and i am getting this value while debugging. i guess there are some issues with model . can anyone point out of my error where i am doing wrong.here is my code
Model:

```
public class JobseekerBackgroundDetail
    {
        [Key]
        public int JobseekerId { get; set; }
        public string HighestDegree { get; set; }
        public string Specialisation { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> PassingYear { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> Percentage { get; set; }
        public string University { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string TechnicalExp { get; set; }
        public string WorkField { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult JobSeekerAddEditEducation(string HighestDegree, string Specialisation, int PassingYear, double Percentage, string University, string Country, string TechnicalExp, string WorkField)
        {
            EmployeeContext employeeContext = new EmployeeContext();
            JobseekerBackgroundDetail jobseekerBackgroundDetail = new JobseekerBackgroundDetail();

            if (Session["LogedUserID"] != null)
            {
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["LogedUserID"]);
                bool exists = employeeContext.JobseekerBackgroundDetails.Any(row => row.JobseekerId == id);
                if (exists != true)
                {
                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        jobseekerBackgroundDetail.JobseekerId = id;
                        jobseekerBackgroundDetail.HighestDegree = HighestDegree;
                        jobseekerBackgroundDetail.Specialisation = Specialisation;
                        jobseekerBackgroundDetail.PassingYear = PassingYear;
                        jobseekerBackgroundDetail.Percentage = Percentage;
                        jobseekerBackgroundDetail.University = University;
                        jobseekerBackgroundDetail.Country = Country;
                        jobseekerBackgroundDetail.TechnicalExp = TechnicalExp;
                        jobseekerBackgroundDetail.WorkField = WorkField;
                        employeeContext.JobseekerBackgroundDetails.Add(jobseekerBackgroundDetail);
                        employeeContext.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    return RedirectToAction("JobSeekerProfile");
                }
                else
                {
                    var query = from p in employeeContext.JobseekerBackgroundDetails
                                where p.JobseekerId == id
                                select p;
                    foreach (JobseekerBackgroundDetail p in query)
                    {
                        p.JobseekerId = id;
                        p.HighestDegree = HighestDegree;
                        p.Specialisation = Specialisation;
                        p.PassingYear = PassingYear;
                        p.Percentage = Percentage;
                        p.University = University;
                        p.Country = Country;
                        p.TechnicalExp = TechnicalExp;
                        p.WorkField = WorkField;
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        employeeContext.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                    }
                    return RedirectToAction("JobSeekerProfile");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("JobSeekerLogin", "JobSeeker");
            }
        }
```

view

```
@model Sample.Models.JobseekerBackgroundDetail
@using (Html.BeginForm("JobSeekerAddEditEducation", "JobSeeker", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="container">

                        @Html.Label("Highest Degree", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.HighestDegree, new {  @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "HighestDegree" })


                        @Html.Label("Specialisation", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Specialisation, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Specialisation" })

                        @Html.Label("Passing Year", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PassingYear,  new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Passing Year" } )


                        @Html.Label("Percentage", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Percentage, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Percentage" })


                        @Html.Label("University", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.University, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "University" })

                        @Html.Label("Country", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Country, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Country" })                       


                        @Html.Label("Technical Exp", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TechnicalExp, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Technical Exp" })


                        @Html.Label("Work Field", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.WorkField, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Work Field" })

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-left col-md-offset-2">Submit</button>

    </div>
}
```

in my model all the values are nullable except the JobseekerId. please help. stuck with this problem which is big for me cant able to find the problem..

Comment: Not related but remove all the parameters in your post method and replace with `JobseekerBackgroundDetail model`.

Comment: In IF check you are getting Id as:   int id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["LogedUserID"]);
  ,I am not sure, from where are you getting Id in ELSE section.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke , sir i have done that but can not find any difference. still getting the same error, else part is working for update but can not work the if part of add

Comment: I'm just pointing out one of the many (sorry to be harsh) bad pieces of code you have. What your doing here does not even make sense. Property  `JobseekerId` is marked with `[Key]` making it unique, but your trying to add rows with duplicate `JobseekerId` values

Comment: thats because i am getting the error `EntityType 'JobseekerBackgroundDetail' has no key defined` thats why i have defined this.

Comment: Then it should have `public int ID { get; set; }` as the Primary Key if you want to have multiple items with `JobseekerId` equal to the current user ID`

Comment: yeah find some article on [link](http://stackoverflow.com) related to this, and i have changed it to JobseekerId to Id and get rid of that [Key] error, but still it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

use this code : 
//Added(optinioal).

```html
public ActionResult actionname(datatype yourclassname)
{
db.Entry(yourclassname).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;
db.savechanges();
}
```

and check your mvc view send all class parameters your action.